# Remove and replace text in .txt file with .BAT file

Tags: list, batch-file, dir

Right now I have a very simple DIR .BAT file to list XLS files. I need to delete the file extension & unneeded parts from the list. What is the simplest way to do this?

Right now I just have this:

```
DIR /b /on *.XLS > LIST.TXT
```

which gives me an output of:

```
00000+00-f.xls
00960+83-f.xls
01911+82-f.xls
01939+53-f.xls
02225+79-f.xls
```

But I would like it to reformat to

```
00000+00
00960+83
01911+82
01939+53
02225+79
```

Any ideas on how to this with just one .BAT file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
(for /f "delims=-" %%a in ('DIR /b /a-d /on *.XLS') do echo %%a)>file.txt
```